# react-navigation title gets truncated

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

I am having trouble with the stacknavigator showing the title on the header bar without truncating it, even though there are no other elements on the header.

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home,
  Bookings,
  UserCenter,
  Help,
  WhatsApp
}, {
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: 'tomato',
    inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
  },
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  animationEnabled: false,
  swipeEnabled: false,
  navigationOptions: {
    tabBarOnPress: ({navigation, defaultHandler}) => {
      if (navigation.state.routeName === 'WhatsApp') {
        Linking.openURL('whatsapp://send?phone=982')
        defaultHandler = () => {}
      } else {
        defaultHandler()
      }
    }
  }
});

Tabs.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];

  // You can do whatever you like here to pick the title based on the route name
  const options = {
    headerTitle: routeName
  }

  if (routeName === 'Home') {
    options.header = null
  }

  return options
};

const App = createStackNavigator({
  Tabs,
  Wallet,
  HelpQuestion,
  Service,
  Category,
  BookNow,
  Favorites,
  BookingSummary,
  Referral,
  Search
}, {
  navigationOptions: {
    headerTintColor: '#000'
  }
})
```

Here's what I get [image: help tab]

As you can notice, the help tab has no other buttons, or anything to take up the space, and yet the title is truncated

Answer (score 1):

If you're not setting a font anywhere, it's probably your phone's system font not playing nicely with React Native. For example I ran into this problem on my OnePlus 5T using the OnePlus Slate font.

Change your app's font to use a standard font like Roboto for Android and Arial for iOS.

See here for more info and how to fix it: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5050